# Setting autovacuum on partitioned tables in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, partition, vacuum, autovacuum, postgresql-11

I'm trying to adjust autovacuum settings on a partitioned table, on PostgreSQL 11.

e.g:

```
# create table test (ts timestamp) partition by range (ts);
CREATE TABLE
# alter table test set (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1);
ERROR:  unrecognized parameter "autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor"
```

Is it possible to alter such settings on partitioned tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can only set parameters on table partitions rather than on parent table.

```
postgres=# create table test (ts timestamp) partition by range (ts);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table test_2018 partition of test for values from ('2018-01-01 00:00:00') to ('2018-12-31 23:59:59');
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# alter table test_2018 set (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1);
ALTER TABLE
postgres=# alter table test set (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1);
ERROR:  unrecognized parameter "autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor"
postgres=#
```